# Width dialog activity 7 inch

Tags: android, layout, dialog, android-activity, width

I've got an dialog activity for uploading files to my app. The problem is that on the 10 inch screens its acting normal, but if I'm testing on a 7 inch the width just get smaller (see picture)

[image: 10 inch]

[image: 7 inch]

Below is my code for the layout I use for the 7 inch:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<!-- Share document wrapper -->
 <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/share_document_wrapper"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp">

    <!-- Document views -->
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/share_document_title"
        android:text="@string/share_document_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"/>

    <!-- Divider -->
    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dip"
        android:background="?android:attr/dividerHorizontal" />
    <!-- /Divider -->
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/share_document_single_selected_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:hint="@string/share_document_hint_edittext"/>
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/share_document_selected_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:visibility="gone"/>
</LinearLayout>

<!-- Share account wrapper -->
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/share_account_wrapper"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp">

    <!-- Account views -->
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/share_account_title"
        android:text="@string/share_account_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"/>

    <!-- Divider -->
    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dip"
        android:background="?android:attr/dividerHorizontal" />
    <!-- /Divider -->

    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/share_account_info_wrapper"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:background="@drawable/sliding_contact_menu_row_selector" >
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/share_account_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<!-- Share project wrapper -->
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/share_project_wrapper"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp">

    <!-- Project and folders views -->
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/share_project_title"
        android:text="@string/share_project_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"/>

    <!-- Divider -->
    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dip"
        android:background="?android:attr/dividerHorizontal" />
    <!-- /Divider -->
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp">
        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/share_project_spinner"
            android:layout_width="500dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:spinnerMode="dialog"/>

        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/share_project_create_new_project"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/green_button"
            android:textColor="@color/MyWhite"
            android:text="+"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>
    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>

<!-- Share folder wrapper -->
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/share_folder_wrapper"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp">

    <!-- Project and folders views -->
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/share_folder_title"
        android:text="@string/share_folder_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"/>

    <!-- Divider -->
    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dip"
        android:background="?android:attr/dividerHorizontal" />
    <!-- /Divider -->
     <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/share_folder_info_wrapper"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:background="@drawable/sliding_contact_menu_row_selector" >
        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/share_loader"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
         <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/share_folder_icon"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:src="@drawable/folder_icon"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/share_folder_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/share_document_wrapper"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp">

    <!-- Documents views -->
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/share_document_title"
        android:text="@string/share_document_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"/>

    <!-- Divider -->
    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dip"
        android:background="?android:attr/dividerHorizontal" />
    <!-- /Divider -->
     <RelativeLayout 
        android:id="@+id/share_document_info_wrapper"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="30dp"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:background="@drawable/sliding_contact_menu_row_selector" >
         <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/share_document_icon"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:src="@drawable/upload_document_purple"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/share_document_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/share_document_icon"/>

        <Switch
            android:id="@+id/share_document_switch"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:switchPadding="200sp"
            android:thumb="@drawable/switch_custom_share"
            android:textOn="Als versie"
            android:textOff="Nieuw"
            android:textColor="@color/MyWhite"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:enabled="false"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/share_warning_message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/share_warning_message" 
        android:textColor="@color/MyRed"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

</LinearLayout>


<!-- Buttons bottom wrapper -->
<View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dip"
    android:background="?android:attr/dividerHorizontal" />
<LinearLayout
    style="?android:attr/buttonBarStyle" 
    android:id="@+id/share_buttons_wrapper"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle" 
        android:id="@+id/share_button_cancel"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/archive_cancel"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>
    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle" 
        android:id="@+id/share_button_upload"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="OK"/>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Because I use a custom theme here is my custom style:

```
<style name="MyShareTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">stateAlwaysHidden</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>
```

**Question:**

How can I let the dialog activity on the 7 inch screen have the same size as the dialog on the 10 inch?

**EDIT:**

As requested, my code for my layout for the 10 inch screens:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<!-- Share document wrapper -->
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/share_document_wrapper"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp">

    <!-- Document views -->
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/share_document_title"
        android:text="@string/share_document_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"/>

    <!-- Divider -->
    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/dividerHorizontal" />
    <!-- /Divider -->
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/share_document_single_selected_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/share_document_hint_edittext"/>
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/share_document_selected_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>
</LinearLayout>

<!-- Share account wrapper -->
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/share_account_wrapper"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp">

    <!-- Account views -->
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/share_account_title"
        android:text="@string/share_account_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"/>

    <!-- Divider -->
    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dip"
        android:background="?android:attr/dividerHorizontal" />
    <!-- /Divider -->

    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/share_account_info_wrapper"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:background="@drawable/sliding_contact_menu_row_selector" >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/share_account_icon"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:src="@drawable/person_icon"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/share_account_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="18sp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<!-- Share project wrapper -->
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/share_project_wrapper"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp">

    <!-- Project and folders views -->
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/share_project_title"
        android:text="@string/share_project_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"/>

    <!-- Divider -->
    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dip"
        android:background="?android:attr/dividerHorizontal" />
    <!-- /Divider -->

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp">
        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/share_project_spinner"
            android:layout_width="500dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:spinnerMode="dialog"/>

        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/share_project_create_new_project"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/green_button"
            android:textColor="@color/MyWhite"
            android:text="+"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<!-- Share folder wrapper -->
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/share_folder_wrapper"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp">

    <!-- Project and folders views -->
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/share_folder_title"
        android:text="@string/share_folder_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"/>

    <!-- Divider -->
    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dip"
        android:background="?android:attr/dividerHorizontal" />
    <!-- /Divider -->
     <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/share_folder_info_wrapper"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:background="@drawable/sliding_contact_menu_row_selector" >
         <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/share_loader"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
         <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/share_folder_icon"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:src="@drawable/folder_icon"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/share_folder_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="18sp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/share_document_wrapper"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp">

    <!-- Documents views -->
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/share_document_title"
        android:text="@string/share_document_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"/>

    <!-- Divider -->
    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dip"
        android:background="?android:attr/dividerHorizontal" />
    <!-- /Divider -->
     <RelativeLayout 
        android:id="@+id/share_document_info_wrapper"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="30dp"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:background="@drawable/sliding_contact_menu_row_selector" >
         <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/share_document_icon"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:src="@drawable/upload_document_purple"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/share_document_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/share_document_icon"/>

        <Switch
            android:id="@+id/share_document_switch"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:switchPadding="200sp"
            android:thumb="@drawable/switch_custom_share"
            android:textOn="Als versie"
            android:textOff="Nieuw"
            android:textColor="@color/MyWhite"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:enabled="false"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/share_warning_message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/share_warning_message" 
        android:textColor="@color/MyRed"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

</LinearLayout>


<!-- Buttons bottom wrapper -->
<View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dip"
    android:background="?android:attr/dividerHorizontal" />
<LinearLayout
    style="?android:attr/buttonBarStyle" 
    android:id="@+id/share_buttons_wrapper"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle" 
        android:id="@+id/share_button_cancel"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/archive_cancel"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>
    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle" 
        android:id="@+id/share_button_upload"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="OK"/>
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Have designed separate layout for the 7inch screen ?

Comment: Yes I have a separate layout for the 7inch screen

Comment: what is the name of the folder in which you kept the two different layout xmls??

Comment: layout-sw720 for the 10 inch and layout for the smaller screens (I only support tablet devices)

Comment: If you have designed layout separately then it automatically set your layout according to the device screen size. If you want it same as 10 inch then fix the height width of your layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a dimen.xml file with the width value of dialog in 10 inch Screen and add a value which is respective to the 7 inch screen. This will Handle the Dialog's width.

Create values-sw600dp folder for 7 - inch and values-sw720dp for 10-inch. In these Folder add a dimen.xml file which with the width value u want. For example

For sw600dp the dimen.xml file

```
<resources>

    <dimen name="popup_width">400dp</dimen>

</resources>
```

For sw72dp the dimen.xml file

```
<resources>

    <dimen name="popup_width">500dp</dimen>

</resources>
```

and add this to the 'layout_width' with as follows

```
layout_width="@dimen/popup_width"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

Give `ScrollView` **width** as `match_parent`

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

**EDIT:**

May be this will help

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/share_document_wrapper"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp">
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer but it didn't work, still stay the same small size. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but if I set layout_width to 0dp I get the following warning/error: Suspecious size: this will make the view invisible, probably intended for layout_height

Comment: @Stitchblade add `android:layout_weight="1"` after width

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I've just copied your linearlayout, and it gave the same error

Answer (score 0):

Set the layout_width property of your **scrollview** to `match_parent`

This will make your dialog activity full screen.
and the margin properties will make it fit equally.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but as Hariahran Tamilan suggested this didn't work for me, any other suggestions?

Comment: Already did, but the 720dp folder layout version has no scrollview, so the problem is not with the folders

Comment: or you can try not creating different layouts. Just keep one xml and check

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I've editted my post, see edit

Comment: try and remove the scrollview from your 7inch layout...i checked for differences in your layouts..there is no major difference except the scrollview..please remove it and try it out once..also..try using just one layout file for both the screens

Comment: Thanks Atish but your suggestion just delete my scrollview but doesnt resolve the width issue, it stay still the same. (that was the reason why I made two different layouts for the screen supports)

Comment: there is some other problem then..can you share your code so that i can run it on my PC and check???